# Using an array of Strings for Binary Search enquiry

Tags: java

I was looking at a previous question submitted a while back and had further inquiry on it. The link is here:

[Java BinarySearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12517764/java-binarysearch)

The first answer give it nearly answers my question, but not fully. In the one shown above the `Array` has a collection of `int` values. However, I have an array that stores `String` values, therefore when I call `Array[mid]` it won't allow this, since mid is an `int` value and not a `String`. I receive the error `" The operator < is undefined for the argument type(s) Entry, String "`, I'm assuming because I'm calling `mid` ( an `int` value ) with an `array` of strings, although `mid` really is a reference to the middle `index` not the actual values stored in the `array`.

I could potentially completely wrong here and therefore seem stupid :P but I'm pretty confused, any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not that you use `mid`, which is an `int`, to index an array of `String`s. This is perfectly fine. 
The problem is that you try to use the `>` operator with `String`s.

To compare `String`s, you can use `compareTo` instead of `>`.

So, instead of:

```
a[mid] < key
```

You would use:

```
a[mid].compareTo(key) < 0
```

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot. Why in the link I provided were they able to use the '>' operator ?

Comment: @user3443834 This operator is defined for the `int` type, as well as some others (`double`, `char`...), but not for `String`s.