# Problems implementing a binary search

Tags: java

I'm feeling very very stupid because I've solved much harder stuff than this.
This is supposed to be an implementation of ordered binary search. Whenever I trace the 12, a stackoverflow error pops up. Any help please?

```
public class binarySearch {        
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = { 1, 5, 6, 8, 12, 88 };
        System.out.println(binaryHelper(0, arr.length - 1, 12, arr));
    }

    public static int binaryHelper(int first, int last, int target, int[] arr) {
        if(first > last) return -1;
        else {
            int mid = first + last / 2;
            if(arr[mid] == target) return mid;
            else if(arr[mid] > target) return binaryHelper(first, mid - 1, target, arr);
            else return binaryHelper(mid + 1, last, target, arr);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java BinarySearch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12517764/java-binarysearch)

Comment: How do you think `first+last/2;` is evaluated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the precedence order of your [operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) in your `mid` variable computation. It should be computed as:

```
int mid = (first + last) / 2;
```

instead of

```
int mid = first+last/2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Error is here:

```
 int mid = first+last/2;
```

this means mid is equal to first + last dividied by 2 which is wrong

so it should be like

```
int mid = (first+last)/2;
```