# binary search on array of integer in java

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, binary-search

I know this is a very famous question and lots of answers provided already, but I am trying to implement binary search algorithm in java of my own.

First of all getting following compilation error, why??

> This method must return a result of type int

Second how this approach differs from [this famous solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249392/binary-search-in-array)

```
public static int binarySearch(int test[], int num){

    int midLength = test.length/2;
    int fullLength = test.length;

    if(num > test[midLength]){
        int newArray[] = new int[fullLength - midLength];
        for (int j = 0; j<= midLength ; j++){
            newArray[j] = test[midLength + j];

        }
        return binarySearch(newArray, num);
    }
    else if(num < test[midLength]){
        int newArray[] = new int[midLength];
        for (int j = 0; j<= fullLength - midLength ; j++){
            newArray[j] = test[j];

        }
        return binarySearch(newArray, num);
    }
    else if(num == test[midLength]){
        return test[midLength];
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int test[] = {2,8,1,6,4,6};
    Arrays.sort(test);
    int num = ArraysTest.binarySearch(test, 1);
    System.out.println(num);
}
```

Please ignore the boundary conditions and logical mistakes, as this is draft version.

Answer (score 2):

There is a missing `return` at the end of your `binarySearch` function. In Java, the compiler verifies that on every possible execution path a return of the right type exists. In your case, if all tests are false, then the execution rises the end of the function where there is no `returned` value, violating the function contract.

Your algorithm differs from the cited one in the way that yours constructs a new array at each ‘‘split’’. So, we can say that it is relatively inefficient because you use too much memory without any real need for it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have an "else" clause in your `binarySearch()` method. This fall-thru case can be done by adding a return statement at the end of the method. In other words, the "else" need not to be explicit. The compiler thinks that there is a possibility that none of the tests (if and else-ifs) will pass, so the method returns nothing. Also, since the method is recursive, it MUST have a default (escape) clause. Otherwise, it will call itself forever.  So, just remove the else-if surrounding `return test[midLength];`.

Answer (score 0):

Jean is right you are not returning any values in the last in your function so what if not any if condition and else-if condition got true.

Second thing when you use else-if you must provide else condition in last so that code doesn't fails anyways.

```
    int midLength = test.length/2;
    int fullLength = test.length;

    if(num > test[midLength]){
        int newArray[] = new int[fullLength - midLength];
        for (int j = 0; j<= midLength ; j++){
            newArray[j] = test[midLength + j];

        }
        return binarySearch(newArray, num);
    }
    else if(num < test[midLength]){
        int newArray[] = new int[midLength];
        for (int j = 0; j<= fullLength - midLength ; j++){
            newArray[j] = test[j];

        }
        return binarySearch(newArray, num);
    }
    else if(num == test[midLength]){
        return test[midLength];
    }

    //if it is not matched with any conditions above.
    else{
        return 0;
    }
```