# How do I find the closest number in an array, without going over?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am making a simple program that determines what time the next train is. I have an array with all the train times, I just don't know how to determine which is the closest to the current time, without going over. Here is what I have so far:

```
var d = new Date();
var hours = d.getHours();
var minutes = d.getMinutes();

var time = hours + minutes;
console.log(time);

var trainTimes = [1125, 1155, 1225, 1255, 1325, 1355, 1425, 1455, 1526, 1629, 1644, 1709];

function nextTrain(time) {

}
```

Within the function `nextTrain()` should I simply do if-else statements, or is there a better method?

Comment: The algorithm is called binary search. I'd be surprised if this question wasn't a duplicate.

Comment: ES6: `let nextTrain = Math.min(...trainTimes.filter(i => i > time))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var d = new Date();
var hours = d.getHours();
var minutes = d.getMinutes();

var time = hours + minutes;
console.log(time);

// given sorted array.
var trainTimes = [1125, 1155, 1225, 1255, 1325, 1355, 1425, 1455, 1526, 1629, 1644, 1709];

// returns nth train 
function nextTrain(num, arr) {
    n = 0
    while (arr[n] <= num){ // consider < vs. <=
      n++;
    }
    return arr[n];
}

console.log(nextTrain(time,trainTimes))
```

idea taken from [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8584902/get-closest-number-out-of-array)

Comment: probably? it should give you 1325

Comment: Oh right, it's the next one. For some reason I thought that even previous should be taken into account as soon as it's closer.

Comment: It means the implementation will fail on `1256` - it would return `1255`

Comment: Thanks for this. All that's left for me to do is implement text-speech :)

Comment: 1700 should give you 1709, which it does

Comment: At the moment when I posted it it was the wrong `>` condition, which lead to the wrong answer.

Comment: < or <= should yield the same result, for the value 1700

Comment: It was `>` and you know that.

Answer (score 5):

Since the array of trainTimes is in order, you could loop through them until you find the first one after the current time, then break.

```
function nextTrain(time) {
  for (i = 0; i<trainTimes.length; i++){
    if(trainTimes[i]>time){
     console.log("the next train is " + trainTimes[i]);
     break;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to do binary search here since your array is already sorted.  You can check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249392/binary-search-in-array) for detail regarding implementation.

After you figure out, where the current time falls in the array, you can calculate the difference of current time with two closest neighbors. This would depend on where your current time falls in the binary tree. Anyway, this method will be efficient.

Comment: Binary search for an array of << 1k size looks like an overkill

Answer (score 0):

You need to multiply your hours by 100.

You could then try something like this:

```
nextTrain(time);

function nextTrain(time) {
    var timeFound = false;
    for(var i = 0; i < trainTimes.length; i++){
        if(time > trainTimes[i - 1] && time < trainTimes[i] && !timeFound ){
            console.log("Next train time is: " + trainTimes[i]);
            timeFound=true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i hope it helps you

```
var d = new Date();
var hours = d.getHours();
var minutes = d.getMinutes();

var time = hours + minutes;
console.log(time);

var trainTimes = [1125, 1155, 1225, 1255, 1325, 1355, 1425, 1455, 1526, 1629, 1644, 1709];
var diff = new Array(12);
for (i = 0; i < trainTimes.length; i++) {
    diff[i] =Math.abs( time + trainTimes[i]);//difference
}
var diff_sort = diff.sort(function(a, b){return a-b});//acs sort
var nearestIndex = diff.indexOf(diff_sort[0]); 
var nearestValue = trainTimes[nearestIndex]; 
alert(nearestValue)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use this:

```
var nextTimeIndex = (trainsTimes.indexOf(time) >= trainsTimes.length) ? 0 : trainsTimes.indexOf(time) + 1;
var nextTrain = trainsTimes[nextTimeIndex];
```