# How to find an object in table C++

Tags: c++, c++11

i have function which finds a number in a table:

```
int find(int arrf[], int len, int seek)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
        if (arrf[i] == seek) 
            return i;
    return -1;
}
```

Is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: Can you sort the array first - or update it to use std::vector?

Comment: Why would there be ? No magic in computers, you have to search one by one...

Comment: @Karol Borecki  It is the linear search. If the array is not sorted then there is no other methods. On the other hand the function implementation is bad. There is already standard algorithm std::find in C++.

Comment: related:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249392/binary-search-in-array

Comment: @UKMonkey how would vector help. Its just a wrapped array

Comment: @Karol Borecki  The function declaration should look at least like size_t find( const int a[], size_t n, int x );

Comment: @pm100 it doesn't help the issue of searching for an item; it helps on # of arguments to the function, maintainability, memory management, abstraction (potentially).

Comment: No i cant sort this first, thanks guys a lot, i just want to make sure this is the best way.

Answer (score 0):

For linear search two optimizations come to mind:

1. Build a vectorized implementation that uses SIMD instructions to do multiple comparisons at the same time.
2. Parallelize search to multiple CPUs. That only makes sense if the array to search is sufficiently large to warrant multi-threading overhead.

Intel [Parallel STL](https://software.intel.com/en-us/get-started-with-pstl) can do both optimizations for you.